# Why does $g$ become 0 for this question?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, collision, free-body-diagram

[image]

A body went up for $4 \;s$ in air and then down for $4 \;s$ with the total journey of $8\;s$. Now, the graph above is a $a-t$ graph for the statement.

My question is that why does $g = 0$ when the body reaches surface. I know that when it reaches the surface, the body doesn’t move. But still, there is an acceleration due to gravity of $9.8m/s^2$ on it. It is just that there is a counter-attacking force but how does that make $a$ on the body $0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is that why does g = 0 when the body reaches surface.

It doesn't! $g$ is the magnitude of the gravitational field of the planet (Earth, in this case). It is $$
|\vec{g}|\simeq\frac{Gm_E}{r^2},$$
where $m_E$ is planet's mass, and $r$ is the distance from the center of the (spherical) planet. At Earth's surface it is approximately 9.8 m/s$^2$, all the time. It just so happens, because of how gravitational forces work, that "the acceleration due to gravity **only** " ('only' is a key word that gets left out) has a magnitude equal to $g$. (This, IMHO, is one of the big failures in physics pedagogy nomenclature.)

Notice that the graph axis is *not* showing $g$. It is showing the acceleration, and that results from the net force at the particular time, not merely the gravitational force.

The gravitational field is always present, exerting a force on the mass. But there may be other forces. The acceleration is the result of the net force.

Comment: Do you mean to say acceleration = 0 but not gravitation force ?

Comment: I feel I consider it to be a ‘Yes’.

Comment: "The gravitational field is always present, exerting a force on the mass. "  That's what I said!

Answer (score 0):

Acceleration is the derivate of speed. If the speed does not change, the acceleration is indeed 0.
As you pointed out, there are 2 forces acting on the body when it lies on the ground. Those 2 forces are equal in magnitude and opposite in direction so the net force (the sum of all the forces) is 0.
Newton's second law is verified: if the net force if zero then the acceleration is also zero.